# MVC AspNetUser get registered User ID

Tags: asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller, asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-membership, membership-provider

I am trying to do the following: I would like to get the registered user ID by receiving the user mail and checking if that mail all ready exists in AspnetUsers table. If it does then get the User ID else create a new user. I have started by doing the following:

```
 if (UserManager.FindByEmail(model.Email) != null)
 {
   // get user Id
   // Update person table
 }else
   //create a new user
 {
```

but I can not get the user ID.

Answer (score 1):

I resolved my issue by doing the following:

```
 if (UserManager.FindByEmail(model.Email) != null)
   {

      var registedUserID = context.AspNetUsers.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Email == model.Email);

     string id= registedUserID.Id; // Now my id is equal to UserMembership Id
  }
```

I got the AspNetUsers where mail equals the mail I recieved then I could get that User Id.

Answer (score 0):

The FindByEmail() should return an ApplicationUser object to you. Just assign it to a local variable and retrieve the Id.

```
var user = UserManager.FindByEmail(model.Email);
if (user != null)
 {
   // get user Id
   var userId = user.Id;
   // Update person table
 }
else
   //create a new user
 {
 }
```